# How can repeat 10 times randomly in several available functions in python?

Tags: python

For several functions: ftn_1, ftn_2, ... , ftnk
I want to repeat 10 times randomly among above.
(The whole time is k^10.)

I find some function which acts like this way but it seems to act just for string : itertools.product

```
def ftn1():
   ...
def ftn2():
   ...
x=0;
itertools.product(x=ftn1(x), x=ftn2(x), .., x=ftnk(x), [repeat=10])
```

I want to do similar to above and find the smallest value for all cases.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing in that `itertools.product()` call. You can't use the same `x` parameter multiple times.

Comment: What do you mean by "10 times randomly"?

Comment: Itertools is for iterating over any kind of sequence, not just strings. The examples use strings because they're simple to see.

Comment: I wanted to update the value x using ftn. It seems bsquare's way is enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a list (or a tuple) of all your functions, and then use random on it, for instance:

```
import random

funcs = [ftn1, ftn2, ftn3, ..., ftnN]
my_func = random.choice(funcs)
```

Then you can call `my_func` with any argument of your choice.

Comment: I didn;t get the `x` meaning

Comment: It was just to fit the call like in the original question; but I'll change it for better legibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have `k` functions and want to call all of them `10` times in total, but in random order, you could `shuffle()` a list of them.
For sanity purposes this example has 3 functions and calls them 2 times. An argument is supplied too for all of them, it is just written out:

```
import random

def f1(x):
  print("f1:"+str(x))
def f2(x):
  print("f2:"+str(x))
def f3(x):
  print("f3:"+str(x))
# here you could have more functions...

repeats=[f1,f2,f3]*2 # ... and they could be listed here, and 2 could be 10
print("Default order:")
for i in range(len(repeats)):
  repeats[i](i) # repeats[i] is a function here, which is invoked with i

random.shuffle(repeats)
print("Shuffled order:")
for i in range(len(repeats)):
  repeats[i](i)
```

Example output (of course it varies because of randomness)

> ```
> Default order:
> f1:0
> f2:1
> f3:2
> f1:3
> f2:4
> f3:5
> Shuffled order:
> f3:0
> f1:1
> f1:2
> f2:3
> f2:4
> f3:5
> ```

Though the number of them is not 3^2, but 3*2.